# PHP MYSQL - How do I create form with multiple dropdowns grouped by day / week

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I have a table called "choices" structured like so....

```
-----------------------------------------------
id | serving_date | serving_description
-----------------------------------------------
1  | 04/07/2016   | Food description goes here
2  | 04/07/2016   | Food description goes here
3  | 04/07/2016   | Food description goes here
4  | 05/07/2016   | Food description goes here
5  | 05/07/2016   | Food description goes here
6  | 05/07/2016   | Food description goes here
7  | 06/07/2016   | Food description goes here
8  | 06/07/2016   | Food description goes here
9  | 06/07/2016   | Food description goes here
11 | 07/07/2016   | Food description goes here
12 | 07/07/2016   | Food description goes here
13 | 07/07/2016   | Food description goes here
-----------------------------------------------
```

I now need to produce an order form in PHP and what I would like to have is a dropdown box for each date, so using the example table above I would like to have 4 dropdowns one for each day, containing the 3 choices available on that day.

I am fine with coding drop down boxes to read the data from another table, but totally stuck on how to go through each row and group the rows by date into separate dropdowns automatically.

Many thanks for any assistance given.

Update...

I have managed to get it working using the following....

```
$current_date = null;
$current_week = null;

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

if ($row["choice_date"] != $current_date) {
$current_date = $row["choice_date"];

echo "<select name=" . $current_date . "";
echo " . $current_date . ";
}
echo '<option value="'.$row['choice_description'].'">'.$row['choice_description'].'</option>';
}
```

The next step is to submit the form for processing, but I am struggling... Normally I would use $_GET with the field name from the form. But in this instance the name is set as the value $current_date and this changes as the script is run.

Is there a way to simply catch all the selections the user has made?

I have also attached a screenshot of the database to make things a little clearer.[choices_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Y26c.png)

Comment: please post you query

Comment: "SELECT * FROM choices WHERE serving_date = '14/07/16'"

Comment: Try "select * from choices where serving_date='14/07/16' group by serving_date,serving_description";

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, basically I don't want to specify the serving date within the query. I need the query to go through each row and group together the 3 choices available on each day and place a separate dropdown for each "group".

Comment: @D.Eales, it seems you want someone to code for you, to solve your task. Can you please narrow down the scope: what have you tried so far, what doesn't work or what problems you faced? This might help as well to structure your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

First get data from database

```
function getResults($conn){
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM choices";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     $dataArray=array(); // Create a blank array
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           $dataArray[$row['serving_date']][]=$row; 
           // Store data in array by date

         }
      return $dataArray;
   }else {
     echo "0 results";
   }

}
```

Your Data wil get in an array where keys are uniques dates and values are values falling on that date,

now you can display a dropdown where you again traverse an array for date and on clicking on any option of dropdown just do condition check of if array_key_exists() for that date and if exist then get data like this

```
print_r($dataArray['Selected Date from Dropdown']);
```

I hope you understood logic behind this

Comment: Thanks will give it a whirl.

Answer (score 0):

First of all same date have same description or different description.

if it's have same description you can use GROUP BY for both column serving_date and serving_description.

Other hand if you have same date with different description, you have to to use GROUP BY serving date.